# Larvel 10 Unisharp File Uplodader showing 404 in live server

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404, unisharp-file-manager

Unisahrp File uploader working fine in xaamp, but after uplodading to server (to sub folder). it showing 404 while click on image upload button

https://www.afterscakes.in/abeservices/test-1
https://www.afterscakes.in/abeservices/test
File manager woks on localhost. but moving to live server it fails showing 404 eror

file upload path: /domains/afterscakes.in/abeAssets

folders on above path : vendor, storage, route, resources, public, node_modules, images, config, database, bootstrap, app, awstats

---

/domains/afterscakes.in/public_html/abeservices

folders on above path :  assets, upload, public, images, etc..

route:

Route::post('/upload', 'PostTasksController@upload');
Route::group(['prefix' => 'laravel-filemanager', 'middleware' => ['web']], function () {
UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Lfm::routes();
});

controller :

file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
      //  $path=$request->file('file')->storeAs('uploads', $fileName, 'public');
      //  return response()->json(['location'=>"/storage/$path"]);

        $imgpath = request()->file('file')->store('uploads', 'public');
        return response()->json(['location' => "/storage/$imgpath"]);

    }


}
[